# Ivory Coast, Africa: What diseases tend to occur there?

Tags: health, africa

I have been doing a project as part of my virus research and traveling to where each form of a certain virus originated. My first destination is the Tai Forest. I am curious on what diseases, specifically in the west, occur in Africa. I also want to know how to prepare for an unlikely event. To be more specific, let me break it down.

**What I Know:**

- The main virus/disease I am researching is the *"Tai Forest ebolavirus"*. Which if the name didn't give it away, it is a type of Ebola.
- I know that it is more common to effect monkeys. That does not mean that we are not asymptomatic, let alone immune to it, however.
- Third, I know I will not be in actual contact with infected monkeys, but instead in 
  contact with the virus under a microscope
- Finally, I know how to prepare and be safe around this virus in particular

**What I Want to Know:**

- What other, possibly more common, diseases are in the western coast of Africa I should look out for?
- If there are, what should I do to prepare for the unlikely event?
- If it is uncurable, what could I do to minimise my chances of getting infected.

Links would be a very helpful source to me, so if you can provide them I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Travel-SE -- you are looking for specific information which is typically of little interest to travellers. More specialized sources should be consulted. Your organization is in the best position to guide you through the relevant safety procedures. Consider consulting a medical professional specializing in infectious and tropical diseases (depending on your country of origin, that might be tricky).

That being said, [CDC has some detailed information about recommended vaccines in Ivory Coast](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/ivory-coast). I'd say malaria and yellow fever are the main risks; hepatitis and typhoid are a concern anywhere in the world with substandard hygiene norms and water treatment. As you already know, Ebola can't be vaccinated against, nor treated, so preventing exposure is your best bet.

Comment: Well, you can't argue with the CDC

Comment: hmm, Meningitis is a nasty one as well. At least Ebola kills quickly...

Comment: and oh, you can argue with CDC. Checked the list for Uzbekistan. The country itself recommends TBE (tick born encephalitis) vaccination, CDC doesn't even mention it as optional for certain groups. Then again, the USA does not have TBE vaccines available (for whatever reason) according to the CDC website.